# Get distinct results (filtered results) of Splunk Query based on a results field/string value

Tags: logging, splunk

I have a splunk query something like

```
index=myIndex* source="source/path/of/logs/*.log" "Elephant"
```

Thus, this brings up about 2,000 results which are JSON responses from one of my APIs that include the world `"Elephant"`. This is kind of what I want - ***However***, some of these results have duplicate `carId` fields, and I only want Splunk to show me the unique search results

The Results of Splunk looks something like this:

```
MyApiRequests {"carId":3454353435,"make":"toyota","year":"2015","model":"camry","value":25000.00}
```

***NOW***, I just want to filter on the `carId`'s that are unique. I don't want duplicates. Thus, I would expect the original value of 2,000 results to decrease quite a bit.

Can anyone help me formulate my Splunk Query to achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

[`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) will be your friend here.

Consider the following:

```
index=myIndex* source="source/path/of/logs/*.log" "Elephant" carId=*
| stats values(*) as * by carId
```

Comment: Interesting. When I try this, I get 0 results back.

Comment: This answer and @Mads Hansen's presume the `carId` field is extracted already.  If it isn't the neither query will work.  The fields can be extracted automatically by specifying either `INDEXED_EXTRACTION=JSON` or `KV_MODE=json` in props.conf.  Otherwise, you can use the `spath` command in a query.  Either way, the JSON must be in the correct format.  For improper JSON, you can use `rex` to extract fields.

Comment: @RichG - ennth indicated the field _seems_ to be "available" already

Comment: Yes, if you do "fields carId" or the "carId=*" as the post stated, it will automatically extract the field "carId" with those values. You can see it if you go to the left side bar of your splunk, it will be extracted there . For some reason, I can only get this to work with results in my _raw area that are in the key=value format. The only thing I can't figure out now is that stats(values) never returns Unique values for me, despite everyone saying it returns only unique values.

Comment: @ennth - are you sure you have the spelling on the field name correct?

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`dedup`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/SearchReference/Dedup)

```
index=myIndex* source="source/path/of/logs/*.log" "Elephant" | dedup carId
```

Comment: Okay I tried piping the results (which there was 2000) into dedup and I get 0 events as the results.... I expected to get a filtered list of the results back. I'm assuming if I had, say 5 duplicates, this would have got returned to me... So Is this how dedup works?

Comment: You *can* use `dedup`. But you generally *shouldn't*. It's a very inefficient operation in Splunk