# Link two Splunk Web queries based on results value

Tags: logging, splunk

I'm using splunk enterprise web (GUI) and I am filtering through some logs of an API. The API has (2) types of logs - one is `"My Api Response"`, which logs the API JSON response output, and the other is `"My Api Request"`, which logs the input JSON. The issue I am investigating is some of my API Request logs contain `null` values for a key/value pair or field in the log called `"carId":null`.

The log in Splunk Web for **both** response/request looks something like this. Both have a "carId" field that I wanted to JOIN or do some kind of match on so I can investigate both request and response logs of the API:
`{"carId":123456789,"make":"toyota","year":"2015","model":"camry","value":25000.00}`

I tried doing a few Slunk Queries like:
`index=MyIndex* source="my/source/path/to/app.log" "My Api Request" AND "\"carId\":null" OR "My Api Response"`

.... but I can never get both logs. It just gives me 1 or the other no matter what.

I was able to filter out the "carId" field with a query like this:

```
index=rtm* source="my/source/path/to/app.log" "My Api Request" "\"carId\":null," 
| rex field=_raw "(\"carId\":)(?<carIdField>[0-9]{1,9})"
| table carIdField
```

...but I want to use this extracted carId for my subsearch so I can further filter "My Api Responses" that only **contain** this carId

or is there an easier way? I'm reading the Splunk documentation and StackOverflow posts and Splunk posts, but it's kind of confusing.

As I said above,  I basically want to have both these requests (`My Api Request` and the `My Api Response` logs) ordered by Timestamp so I can see the API Requests that only had a `null` value for carId (I don't care about the ones that had real values, since that is expected) and I want to see the corresponding `Api Response` that correlates to that request (that would have the same `carId`). I guess another issue is I can have duplicate `My Api Request` or `My Api Response` logs, as it will log each time someone clicks/POSTS to the API, so it would be nice to filter those out, but I suppose for starters it would be nice to get a working query.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67424702/4418

Comment: You need parenthesis to group the conditions.  if you want requests and responses with a null carId then you want `index=MyIndex* source="my/source/path/to/app.log" "\"carId\":null" ("My Api Request" OR "My Api Response")`